# GPIO access from Voice Bonnet

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gpio, google-aiy

I have a Google AIY Voice Kit. I want to use the raspberry pi to create a water dispenser system. I need access to the GPIO to connect relay and motors. Can I access them via Google Voice Bonnet or I have to remove it? I want to use the voice chip in parallel.

Any suggestions on how I can have direct access to the GPIO via voice bonnet?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several GPIO pins available for use on the Voice Bonnet. You can access them through the `gpiozero` library and the `aiy.pins` package.

There are example scripts available on the [AIY GPIO Expansion Pins](https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice/#makers-guide--gpio-expansion-pins) doc page, but your code would start with something like:

```
from gpiozero import Motor
from aiy.pins import (PIN_A, PIN_B) 

motor=Motor(forward = PIN_A, backward = PIN_B)

#Insert motor behavior here
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to find the doc page you shared. Its very helpful.